# Multiple Page Core Text Parser (Single Column)

Tags: ios, core-text

I want to create an app that displays a bundled text file in core text (swipe to next page) with this type of format:

- Punjabi Language Text
- Punjabi Transliteration to english
- Punjabi Translation to english

But I want users to be able to select the languages displayed via the settings tab, I know how to do that part i.e. NSUserDefaults and Bools. But I wanted to know if there was any code out there that allowed me to parse a certain part of the text file if a certain boolean was true? so maybe say:

```
if (Language == true){
Do parse of every 3rd line after the 1st
} else{
//Nothing
}
if (Transliteration == true){
Do parse of every 3rd line after the 2nd
} else{
//Nothing
}
if (Translation == true){
Do parse of every 3rd line after the 3rd
} else{
//Nothing
}
```

I modified ray wenderlich's (http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text) core text magazine sample code to do most of it i just need help modifying the parser... any help?

Answer (score 0):

core-text does not support text-selection, you need to implementation by yourself which might be a lot of work, check the [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView) as example